# Is there any way we can update the link added to the app in webview dynamically without updating the app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I've been working on an app which displays a list of websites when click on it will be redirected to webview in the app itself, I'm unable to find a way how to update the links dynamically without updating the app. So, If I want users to interact with new links the new links should automatically be updated in the app without update and in the webview too. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You will have to use online database for that. and firebase is best for this type of work. you can create collection with all links and read this collection on app open, you can update links from firebase database collection too. so whenever link will update it will also change in app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use firebase remote config feature, which best fits in your case.

> Firebase Remote Config is a cloud service that lets you change the
>   behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to
>   download an app update.

Well to do that you first need to create a project in [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com)

In remote config feature you can add data in key-value pair. Like in this image:
[image]

I have added two key-value pair, as can add as much as you want. Now in the app side you have to add dependency:
 `implementation ‘com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0’`

And to fetch the values which you have added in firebase, you can easily get those url but first you need to follow some steps to do that. You can check [this](https://proandroiddev.com/firebase-remote-config-on-android-55a27f578505) simple tutorial.

**Note:** To get the values from firebase remote config you must need to click on publish changes button(Which you can see in above image top right corner).

Answer (score 1):

You can store that link to a server and return that link when the app hits a certain API of that server. But for doing that, you need to setup a server, build a server application if you haven't already. Which is a lot of work for just storing a website link.

Another option could be, you can use services like `http://bit . ly` and create a custom link from that service, like `http://bit . ly/my_specific_domain` and use this link in your app. When you need to point to a different website, you can just update where `http://bit . ly/my_specific_domain` redirects to.

But you best bet would be to use Firebase Remote Config, which is both reliable and easy to implement, but that is already described in previous answer.